# Jax-rs list not return in spring-boot(xml format)

Tags: xml, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jax-rs

I try to write JAX-RS web service for my project.When i use TEXT_PLAIN the web service returns my given output. But I want to add APPLICATION_XML file.When I change it to XML it doesn't shows anything.I added **@XmlRootElement** for my model.. What is the error

This is my controller

```
package lk.slsi.controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import lk.slsi.domain.Importer;
import lk.slsi.domain.Product;
import lk.slsi.security.domain.AuthenticatedUser;
import lk.slsi.services.permitServices;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 2/15/2017.
 */
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@Path("release")
public class PermitlController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PermitlController.class);

    private static final String PERMIT_MANAGE_REDIRECT = "redirect:/permitManage";

    @Autowired
    private permitServices permitServices;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/executeRegisterPermit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String executeRegisterAgent(@ModelAttribute("permitForm")
            @Valid CustomsPermit customsPermit,
            BindingResult result,
            HttpSession session) {
        logger.info("Request received to register new agent. [{}]", customsPermit);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.error("Rejecting the request due to binding errors, [{}]", result.getFieldErrors());
            return "redirect:/somethingWentWorng/dataValidationError";
        }
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        long userId = 0;
        String agency = "";
        String units = "";
        List<String> roles;
        if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
            AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
            userId = auth.getUserId();
            agency = auth.getAgency();
            roles = auth.getUserRoles();

            if (agency.equalsIgnoreCase("SLSI")) {
                if (roles.contains("SDD")) {
                    if (permitServices.registerPermit(customsPermit)) {
                        logger.info("Permit registered successfully");
                        session.setAttribute("message", "Permit registered successfully");
                    } else {
                        session.setAttribute("message", "Error occurred while registering the Permit");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return PERMIT_MANAGE_REDIRECT;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/permitManage")
    public String viewManageAgentPage(Model model) {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        long userId = 0;
        String agency = "";
        String units = "";
        List<String> roles;
        if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
            AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
            userId = auth.getUserId();
            agency = auth.getAgency();
            roles = auth.getUserRoles();

            if (agency.equalsIgnoreCase("SLSI")) {
                if (roles.contains("SDD")) {
                    return "permitManage";
                } else {
                    return "redirect:/";
                }
            } else {
                return "redirect:/";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/viewPermit/slsi/Releasedby/Slsi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String viewUpdateAgentPage(@ModelAttribute("SNumber") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("permit", permitServices.getFromId(id));
        return "viewPermitCustoms";
    }

    //This cord for web Service
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomsPermit>> listAllPermits() {
        List<CustomsPermit> viewPermits = permitServices.findAll();
        if (viewPermits.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomsPermit>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomsPermit>>(viewPermits, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    //End of web Service
}
```

This is my configuration class

```
package lk.slsi.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("TransferPermit/restAPI")
public class restConfig extends Application{

}
```

This is my Model

```
package lk.slsi.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomsPermit")
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomsPermit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "permit_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "EntryNumber")
    private String SNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "Application_ID")
    private String applicationID;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PermitReleaseDate")
    private String appPostdate;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String dtIssue;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PostedUserId")
    private String userID;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cusdecNo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String importerVAT;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String importerDetails;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String invoiceNo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String invoiceValue;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String totQty;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String UoM;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String hsCod;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String productDesc;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String blNo;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond1;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond2;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond3;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond4;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond5;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond6;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSNumber() {
        return SNumber;
    }

    public void setSNumber(String SNumber) {
        this.SNumber = SNumber;
    }

    public String getApplicationID() {
        return applicationID;
    }

    public void setApplicationID(String applicationID) {
        this.applicationID = applicationID;
    }

    public String getAppPostdate() {
        return appPostdate;
    }

    public void setAppPostdate(String appPostdate) {
        this.appPostdate = appPostdate;
    }

    public String getDtIssue() {
        return dtIssue;
    }

    public void setDtIssue(String dtIssue) {
        this.dtIssue = dtIssue;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getCusdecNo() {
        return cusdecNo;
    }

    public void setCusdecNo(String cusdecNo) {
        this.cusdecNo = cusdecNo;
    }

    public String getImporterVAT() {
        return importerVAT;
    }

    public void setImporterVAT(String importerVAT) {
        this.importerVAT = importerVAT;
    }

    public String getImporterDetails() {
        return importerDetails;
    }

    public void setImporterDetails(String importerDetails) {
        this.importerDetails = importerDetails;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    public String getInvoiceValue() {
        return invoiceValue;
    }

    public void setInvoiceValue(String invoiceValue) {
        this.invoiceValue = invoiceValue;
    }

    public String getTotQty() {
        return totQty;
    }

    public void setTotQty(String totQty) {
        this.totQty = totQty;
    }

    public String getUoM() {
        return UoM;
    }

    public void setUoM(String UoM) {
        this.UoM = UoM;
    }

    public String getHsCod() {
        return hsCod;
    }

    public void setHsCod(String hsCod) {
        this.hsCod = hsCod;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getBlNo() {
        return blNo;
    }

    public void setBlNo(String blNo) {
        this.blNo = blNo;
    }

    public String getCond1() {
        return cond1;
    }

    public void setCond1(String cond1) {
        this.cond1 = cond1;
    }

    public String getCond2() {
        return cond2;
    }

    public void setCond2(String cond2) {
        this.cond2 = cond2;
    }

    public String getCond3() {
        return cond3;
    }

    public void setCond3(String cond3) {
        this.cond3 = cond3;
    }

    public String getCond4() {
        return cond4;
    }

    public void setCond4(String cond4) {
        this.cond4 = cond4;
    }

    public String getCond5() {
        return cond5;
    }

    public void setCond5(String cond5) {
        this.cond5 = cond5;
    }

    public String getCond6() {
        return cond6;
    }

    public void setCond6(String cond6) {
        this.cond6 = cond6;
    }
}
```

I got this error when run on the web service

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet lk.slsi.config.restConfig threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet lk.slsi.config.restConfig threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet lk.slsi.config.restConfig threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/process/ServerProcessingBinder$DefaultBackgroundSchedulerProvider
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.ServerProcessingBinder.configure(ServerProcessingBinder.java:133)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.install(AbstractBinder.java:329)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerBinder.configure(ServerBinder.java:94)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 logs.
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>lk.slsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>slsi-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>1.0.0</tag>
    </scm>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/public/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>


        <!--Add mysql dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you show your pom.xml file?

Comment: Why are you trying to use both Jersey and Spring MVC annotations together?

Comment: @Aditya .I added pom.xml

Comment: @peeskillet . I'm newer to jax-rs . Please tell me how can do this...